# Load a class at run time in a scala project

Tags: scala, reflection

I would like to load some scala class at runtime, the class are presents in my scala project.
More precisely, in the root folder of my project, I have the TmpCaseClass.scala :

```
class TmpHBaseCaseClass(val adresse:String,val age:Int,val nom:String,val id:Int,val salaire:Float)
```

I would like to compile it and use it at run time using toolBox like this :

```
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse("./TmpCaseClass.scala"))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
  val ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()(0)
  val instance = ctor.newInstance()
```

But I encounter the follwing error :

> Exception in thread "main" scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError:
>   reflective compilation has failed:
>
> illegal start of definition   at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.throwIfErrors(ToolBoxFactory.scala:316)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.parse(ToolBoxFactory.scala:291)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:417)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:414)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.liftedTree2$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:355)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:355)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.parse(ToolBoxFactory.scala:414)
>     at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:17)  at
>   Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:13)    at
>   scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)    at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)   at
>   scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
>     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)   at Main$.main(Main.scala:13)
>     at Main.main(Main.scala)

The line 17 (where the error happens) corresponds to :

```
val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse("./TmpCaseClass.scala"))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
```

How could I get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to parse file contents, instead of file name.

2) Also you wont be able to cast to `Class`, since compilation returns `Unit`. You might want to put another line like `scala.reflect.classTag[TmpCaseClass].runtimeClass`. You can also get tree (AST) as a result of `tb.parse`, if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the error anymore but now I don't know what I should do. I did instance.getClass.getFields.foreach(x => println(x.getName)) but nothing is printed. I don't know how to use the object I just builded.